# How to comment lines in Kusto language

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a way to comment lines / explain query code with comments in Kusto language (KQL) / Azure Data Explorer queries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may need to share more details and your problem statement  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use // to comment lines:

```
// This is a comment
print x="hi"
```

Comment: Is there a multione as well? I've tried `/*` which usually is combined with `//` but it doesn't work. Have you found one because commenting is not documented.

Comment: comment: ctrl+/
uncomment: ctrl+/